# Magento2 Add $20 discount to users (both Login & Guest) who subscribe for Newsletter & a coupon code to apply this discount, validity of 4 weeks

Tags: magento2, discount, newsletter-subscriber

Magento2 Enterprise Edition - I need to provide $20 discount to users (both Login & Guest) who subscribe for Newsletter

- A coupon code to apply this discount & the validity of 4 weeks
- Basically I tried by creating a cart rule, but it is validating only Registered User & not Guest.

How can I achieve this? Any help will be appricated.